# Disable Hyperlink Left Click but allow Right Click

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, click

I would like to display a partially disabled hyperlink in that left click does nothing - and the right click brings up the usual 'Open in New window' etc Context menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you just need to have an onclick handler that calls event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation() on the click event.

```
document.getElementById('someid').onclick = function(e){return e.preventDefault() && e.stopPropagation();};
```

The right click should still work as expected because it comes from a different dom event (oncontextmenu).

Comment: I accepted this answer - primarily because it made me go find out about the preventDefault and stopPropagation functions, but also becuase just maybe the stopPropagagtion might prevent some issue down the line.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `onclick` event attribute in your HTML.

```
<a id="someId" href="https://www.google.com/" onclick="return false;">some link..</a>
```

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pj99q2k0/1/)

As suggested by [zfrisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3700849/zfrisch) in the comments, you could separate js from your markup by attaching an event handler like so -

```
document.getElementById("someId").onclick = function() {
  return false;
};
```

Comment: Generally you want to strive for separation of concerns and keep your programming, markup, and styling separate. It makes all code easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can

```
$('#yourlink').click( function () {
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onclick="return false;"` in your anchor tag..

For React you can use following code

```
<a href="/target-link"  onClick={e=>e.preventDefault()}>
      Click here
</a>
```

Comment: This does not do what the op was asking for. In order to answer the question, you should only `preventDefault` if it was a left click. Also, it's `onclick`, not `onClick`. Also, the syntax seems to be strange to me, but I did not test it.

Comment: Yeah, for JavaScript `return false` or `preventDefault` is enough.. I also included code for `ReactJs` because most of websites moving to React/Angular so it may be helpful for someone

Comment: It is not helpful in this case. The question is about Javascript and there is no mention of React or Angular, so we have no reason to assume that the op is using React or Angular, therefore we need to provide solutions that are not using those. It seems you did not understand my main point. Your `onclick="return false;"` will prevent the default behavior of ALL clicks, while, as the question clearly specifies, the op wants right-click to be working normally, so in the handler you **must** check whether it is a left click and only then prevent the default behavior.

Comment: It is not very relevant whether you do it with `return false;` or `preventDefault`. Relevant is that you shouldn't indiscriminately `return false;` for any clicks like you do. So, your answer is incorrect, as it prevents the default behavior for all cases rather than just in the case of right-click and, your answer drifts away from the topic when you add React code to it, which has no relevancy in an answer to a question unrelated to React.